# What does this site gain by coming out of beta?

Tags: discussion

There are several questions asking when this site will come out of beta.  This seems to be a concern for several users.

Please excuse my ignorance but what does this site gain by coming out of beta?  More traffic? Paid users? :)

Comment: Paid User - No. But definately Paid Ads for the casual visitors.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's little *functional* difference when a site graduates. A beta site is, essentially, *fully functional.* There’s no harm in staying in public beta, so long as the quality of the Q&A is high and the site does not become a ghost town.

But there are added benefits to graduation.

#### A Site Design

The site gets its final design. The generic beta design is nice, but it is *generic*, by design. After graduation, new visitors will see a *form* that fits the *function* of the site.

#### A Link in the Footer

Personal Finance will get a link at the bottom of every page in the Stack Exchange Network. The link in the footer is good for traffic. People often forget that this cross-pollination is so helpful to a site's growth.

#### Moderator Elections

A final stage stage to establishing your governance. Early on, we [appointed several moderators](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) to engage the community in both the community-building issues and site management. But elections are that final phase, where everyone has their say and take part in "owning the process."

#### Migration Paths

Okay, that's a bit of added functionality. When a site graduates, the migration paths are activate which means that post that would be better served elsewhere on the network can be migrated there automatically by community vote; Same for incoming posts *from* the Network.

#### Network Lock-In

Graduation tells the community (and everyone else) "you finally made it." That's why we're waiting for that expected upturn in traffic site before launching the site. If all goes well, graduated sites also get some additional press/media/blog/article coverage from the notoriety surrounding a grand opening. That provides a nice source of traffic to the site.

Answer (score 8):

Finish is just a small issue.
The key I think when the site comes out of Beta is it would mean to all
"The site has all the abilities to grow and sustain all by itself"

This is more like graduation, if you pass the final exam it means that you have learned all that was to learn. Some students are knowledgable without have to study for 4 years, while others even after studying dont have knowledge. Passing the Final exam gives a stamp of approval and by and large ensures sccess of the student.

Like wise if the site can meet the strigent guidelines and pass it, it means that the site has eveything that would make it a success.

Answer (score 7):

I'll add:

**Fair & Democratic Moderator Elections.**

*(Should I start my campaign early? :-)*

Comment: By the way...the moderators on this site are excellent.  I've posted on other stack exchange sites and was not greeted with the same courtesy and consideration as the moderators on this site.  I know I don't always follow the guidelines of the site (yes...I like posting some baiting questions for discussion) but I'm always politely told when I get too far out of line - for some reason it always seems to be George...he has really grown on me.  Anyways...keep up the great work.

Comment: Do you really need to campaign :) I though you would by special privilege of proposing the site, defacto continue being the moderator ;)

Comment: Thanks Muro, and thanks Dheer, but I don't want special treatment, just your votes :-D

Answer (score 4):

Style.  I believe more folks will stick around if the style is nicer.  There will already be a big audience, but it would grow faster and have more new blood if it look finished.

Also, big referring links from other popular sites, so more traffic in general.