# 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Personal Finance & Money's [1st moderator election](https://money.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: MrChrister] [image: JoeTaxpayer] [image: JohnFx]

They'll be taking over for [the existing crew](https://money.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Be sure to give a hearty "Thank you!" to [the Moderators Pro Tempore](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) who served this community during the beta: [Alex B](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/815/alex-b), [Chris W. Rea](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/3/chris-w-rea), [George Marian](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/868/george-marian), [MrChrister](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/91/mrchrister) and [C. Ross](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/312/c-ross).

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5957251575578624/0).

Answer (score 10):

A hearty *thank you* to all the pro-tem moderators: Alex B, George Marian, MrChrister, and C. Ross. And a special one for Chris W. Rea for initiating this site as SE V1.0 and then seeing it to fulfillment as part of SE 2.0.

Welcome to all the newly-elected moderators: MrChrister, JoeTaxpayer and JohnFx. Thank you for volunteering to keep the site alive and meaningful.

Comment: I echo your sentiments (with minor edits ;) ... and thank you!

Comment: I too echo your sentiments but without any edits. To those who are stepping down, those who stepped down previously, and to those who have been elected, heartfelt thanks for making this a better site.